# Android Studio - IOS Simulator not working

Tags: android, ios, flutter

As soon as I adjusted the app icon size and I tried to re-run the app I got this error and the simulator wouldn't start. I tried it on the Android simulator and it works fine. Not sure what I did wrong.

From Terminal: [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Mac OS X 10.15.1 19B88, locale

en-US)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.2.1)

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

From Android Studio:

resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed

```
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

note: Using new build system

note: Planning build

note: Constructing build description
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.

Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.

Comment: What's the error it's showing in the `run tab`?

Comment: When I run Flutter Clean inside terminal it shows:
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter.

Comment: @JosephVeal-Briscoe it clearly says u need to run flutter clean command from the path where the `pubspec.yaml` is present. Can you show the folder structure and path from where you run this command

Comment: Fixed it:      https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1940/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the workspace settings to Legacy build system, 
`Xcode -> File -> Workspace Settings -> Build Systems` change from

```
New Build System(default) -> Legacy Build System
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it. Thank you all.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1940/_index.html